# How to access response from Paypal Express Checkout?

Tags: paypal

I am integrating PayPal Express Checkout as shown here.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/

I am processing the payment successfully, when the transaction has been authorized I am using `actions.payment.get();` to get the information about the transaction.

This returns an object called `SyncPromise` with all the data I want to use. 
    [console screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4d0Z.jpg)

I have tried:

`var response = actions.payment.get();`
   `response.value`

But I get `undefined`.

Does anyone how can I access the object element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call like so:

`actions.payment.get().then(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});`